# Save Matched Perl Regex as Variable

Tags: regex, perl, scripting

I have a simple Perl regex that I need to save as a variable.

If I print it:

```
print($html_data  =~ m/<iframe id="pdfDocument" src=.(.*)pdf/g);
```

It prints what I want to save, but when trying to save it with:

```
$link = $html_data =~ m/<iframe id="pdfDocument" src=.(.*)pdf/g;
```

I get back a '1' as the value of `$link`. I assume this is because it found '1' match.  But how do I save the content of the match instead?

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matched subexpressions of a pattern are saved in variables `$1`, `$2`, etc.  You can also get the entire matched pattern (`$&`) but this is expensive and should be avoided.

The distinction in behavior here, by the way, is the result of scalar vs. list context; you should get to know them, how they differ, and how they affect the behavior of various Perl expressions.

Answer (score 7):

Note the /g to get all matches. Those can't possibly be put into a scalar. You need an array.

```
my @links = $html_data =~ m/<iframe id="pdfDocument" src=.(.*)pdf/g;
```

If you just want the first match:

```
my ($link) = $html_data =~ m/<iframe id="pdfDocument" src=.(.*)pdf/;
```

Note the parens (and the lack of now-useless /g). You need them to call m// in list context.

Comment: The /g in scalar context is just fine if you're trying to do the same thing it does. You don't need it to get the list of the captures though.

Comment: @brian d foy, I didn't say */g in scalar context* isn't useful. I didn't even say it wasn't useful here. I said *scalar context* isn't useful here. (Though it can still be done in scalar context: `my $link = $html_data =~ m/.../ ? $1 : undef;`)

Answer (score 0):

From 'perlfunc' docs:

print LIST
Prints a string or a list of strings.

So,`print m//`, where m// determines that the return value
wanted (wantarray?) is a list
(It appers m// without capture groups returns 1 or 0 match pass
or fail, where as m//g returns a list of matches).

and

`$link` = m//  can only be scalar (as opposed to list) context.
So, m// returns match results 1 (true) or 0 (false).

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote code like this. It may help. It's basically like yours except mine has a few more parentheses.

```
my $path = `ls -l -d ~/`;
#print "\n path is $path";
($user) = ($path=~/\.*\s+(\w+)\susers/);
```

So yours from this example may be something like this if your trying to store the whole thing? I'm not sure but you can use mine as an example. I am storing whatever is in (\w+):

```
($link) = ($html_data =~ (m/<iframe id="pdfDocument" src=.(.*)pdf/g));
```